# Quarkus profile aware file properties not found

Tags: java, quarkus

I've got two configuraiton files in my Quarkus app (version 2.15.3.Final):

```
application.properties
application-dev.properties
```

I run my application with:

```
quarkus dev
```

so the Quarkus `dev` profile is active, but when I try to read the properties inside `application-dev.properties` they are not found.
On the other hand, if I move the property into the main `application.properties` they are found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: by default it loads application.properties during run time you need to pass the property configuration or profile.

quarkus dev -Dquarkus.config.file=application-dev.properties

Comment: It works, but it's a crappy implementation of the solution. Quarkus should look for, automatically, profile aware files linked with the active profiles.

Comment: then I guess refer dev properties in application.properties 
               ---->quarkus.application.config-file=application-dev.properties

Comment: Now yes, it makes more sense, thank you. In fact, the first solution didn't worked me because my project is multi-module, and even passing the -Dquarkus.config.file variable, it was not finding it.